# Generic way to avoid pylints broad-except?

Tags: python, exception, pep8

PEP8 doesn't like *broad* exception handling like

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception:
    handle_exception()
```

I know, there are good reasons for this like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` being handled in an un-inteded way or missing important error-cases.

But sometimes I think I *have to* handle "all other" exceptions like in this case:

```
while True:
    try:
        result = handle_request(get_request())
    except (all, my, known, exceptions) as ex:
        sophisticated_exception_handling()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except Exception as ex:
        # handle exotic situations which just didn't happen before
        result = "something bad happened: %r" % ex
```

In this example I don't want to have my message loop interrupted just because 
some sub routine raises an exception I just didn't think about yet.

Of course I could just `# pylint: disable` this line to get no warning - but that doesn't feel like the most sophisticated answer.

**So my question is:**

Is there some cool approach to nicely handle all exceptions and thus never fall out of my message handling loop without just ignoring a PEP8 warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent "too broad exception" in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442236/how-to-prevent-too-broad-exception-in-this-case)

Comment: Why do you feel "I have to handle "all other" exceptions" ? is there no way to validate the incoming data in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a "special case, based on practicality, which should beat purity" mentioned in PEP20:

```
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
```

... and...

```
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
```

I believe your code does not violate PEP20 (aka [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))